# A "functional" definition of simple group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, simple-groups

We usually give the definition of simple group as follows,

> **Simple Group.** A group $(G,\circ)$ is said to be simple if it contains no *proper nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$*.

Where by trivial normal subgroup of a group $G$ we mean $\langle e\rangle$ where $e$ is the identity element of $G$.

Also, we may give the definition of a connected topological space as follows,

> **Connected Topological Space.** A topological space $(X,\mathfrak{T})$ is said to be connected if it contains no *proper nontrivial clopen subset of $X$*.

I couldn't help but notice the similarity between these two definitions (especially the italicized parts of the definitions) and so I tried to formulate the definition of Simple Groups in an analogous manner of the following definition of Connected Topological Spaces,

> A topological space $(X,\mathfrak{T})$ is said to be connected if for all continuous function $f:X\to\{0,1\}$, it is constant.

A "natural" analogue of this definition in case of simple groups can be,

> **Definition.** A group $(G,\circ)$ is said to be simple if for all homomorphisms $f:G\to\mathbb{Z}_2$, it is constant.

However, I can't prove (or disprove) whether the above definition is equivalent to the definition of simple groups that I mentioned previously.

**Questions**

> - Can anyone help me in this?
> - If the definition is not equivalent then can some "functional" definition of a simple group be given?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That definition is not correct.  For instance, the group $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is simple, but the identity homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_2\to\mathbb{Z}_2$ is nonconstant.  Or if $G$ is any finite group of odd order, any homomorphism $G\to\mathbb{Z}_2$ is constant, but $G$ need not be simple.  The problem is that in contrast with clopen subsets of a topological space, you can't just take a normal subgroup $K\subset G$ and get a homomorphism $G\to\mathbb{Z}_2$ by mapping $K$ to $0$ and every other element of $G$ to $1$.  That usually won't be a homomorphism.

A correct "functional" definition of a simple group is that a nontrivial group $G$ is simple if any homomorphism $f:G\to H$ from $G$ to any other group is either injective or trivial (where "trivial" means it sends every element to the identity).  Indeed, a homomorphism is injective iff its kernel is the trivial subgroup and trivial iff its kernel is all of $G$, so this is just saying the only normal subgroups of $G$ are the trivial subgroup and $G$.

(Aside: I require $G$ to be nontrivial in this definition because the trivial group is not simple; similarly, the empty topological space is not connected (see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/too+simple+to+be+simple).  You can avoid stating that $G$ is nontrivial by saying instead that every homomorphism $f:G\to H$ is exactly one of injective and trivial.  Similarly, you can fix the definition of connectedness by saying every continuous $f:X\to\{0,1\}$ has exactly one point in its image.)

Comment: Actually I was trying to find a group theoretic analogue of connected spaces. A crucial and important thing in the definition of connected is the constantness of the function. However in this case we lack that. Can you suggest some topological analogue of simple group?

Comment: The only analogue I can think of is a space with exactly 2 points: those are the spaces which have exactly two quotients, namely themselves and the trivial (1-point) quotient.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one homomorphism of the cyclic group of order $9$ into the group of order $2$ (the zero homomorphism) but that group is not simple.